# Extend sub-Markov semigroup to Markov semigroup on larger space containing an isolated point

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, markov-process

In [General Theory of Markov Processes](https://books.google.com/books?id=lMpIvtIgFiMC&pg=PA62&lpg=PA62&dq=%22The+Lifetime+Formalisms%22&source=bl&ots=xluFueVzzB&sig=ACfU3U0AjxzUFoCGzlbANQpdZc5bB66naQ&hl=de&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjKlc-S59L2AhULIMUKHb69Cc0Q6AF6BAgCEAM#v=onepage&q=%22The%20Lifetime%20Formalisms%22&f=false), a sub-Markov semigroup on a measurable space $(E,\mathcal E)$ is extended to larger space containing an isolated point $\Delta\not\in E$ in the following way:

[image]

> Why is this well-defined? Unless I'm missing something, $\tilde P_t(x,B)$ is not defined if $B$ is a proper superset of $\{\Delta\}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's implicit that $\tilde P_t(x,\cdot)$ is a probability measure on $E_\Delta$. Thus, if $B=A\cup\{\Delta\}$ with $A\subset E$ then for $x\in E$,
$$
\tilde P_t(x,B)=\tilde P_t(x,\Delta)+\tilde P_t(x,A)=[1-P_t(x,E)]+P_t(x,A).
$$

Comment: Ah, I see. Thank you for your answer. The author claims that if $\tilde X_t$ is a right-continous strong Markov process evolving according to $\tilde P_t$ and $\eta:=\inf\{t\ge0:\tilde X_t\}$, then the strong Markov property would imply that $\tilde X_t=\Delta$ for all $t\ge\zeta$ almost surely. However, I think there are several issues. For example, don't we need to assume that $P_t(x,E)<1$ for all $t$ in order to ensure that $\{t\ge0:\tilde X_t\}$ is nonempty almost surely?

Comment: If $\eta=+\infty$, then there's nothing much to say.